# My notification/observer between two views works only after i go forth and back

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

as the title stated i want to change my label text which is located in the second view. but it is not working from the first button click i need to go forth and back for it to change can someone assist me in this?

here is my first initial view controller which contains the travel button to the second

```
import UIKit

let vc1 = ViewController()
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func QickModeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: quickgameNotificationKey)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name , object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func chooseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: bestof3NotificationKey)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name , object: nil)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    }
```

and here is the second one where the label is

```
import UIKit


extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                       green: .random(in: 0...1),
                       blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

let bestof3NotificationKey = "co.Drake.bestof3"
let quickgameNotificationKey = "co.Drake.quick"

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let bestof3 = Notification.Name(rawValue: bestof3NotificationKey)
    let quick = Notification.Name(rawValue: quickgameNotificationKey)

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBOutlet var CommunicationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var playAgainoutlet: UIButton!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            self.createobservers()


            winningLabel.isHidden = true
            winningLabel.center = CGPoint(x: winningLabel.center.x, y: winningLabel.center.y - 400)
      playAgainoutlet.isHidden = true
            playAgainoutlet.center = CGPoint(x: playAgainoutlet.center.x, y: playAgainoutlet.center.y + 400)
    }





    func createobservers(){
        // quick mode button observer
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateLabel(notification:)), name: quick, object: nil)

        // bestof3 mode button observer
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateLabel(notification:)), name: bestof3, object: nil)

    }



    @objc func updateLabel(notification:NSNotification){


            let isbestof3 = notification.name == self.bestof3 // this here is setting up a variable if notification.name == bestof3 (isbestof3 will then be equal to true)
            let labeltext = isbestof3 ? "Best of 3" : "quick"
            self.CommunicationLabel.text = labeltext



    }


}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you mean that `ViewController2` is the base one and `ViewController` is the second one? They may be either mixed up in this question or mixed up in your code (which might explain the issue)

Comment: Yes sorry the names of the VCs are incorrect but as it shows I am trying to jump from the initial view controller to the second via a button click. the label in the second view controller is not changing until i go back and then go again.

Answer (score 1):

The second `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
        self.createobservers()
```

is not called because it's not presented yet. There are no observers till the view is shown. (`loaded`)

Comment: and how do i get by it?

Comment: first time you present that vc pass the needed value , after that it'll be a live for any notifications